# Выделить из массива типа string дробное число и перезаписать его во второй массив типа double

Tags: регулярные-выражения, java

Язык java
Собственно, вот: дано "Фамилия результат", например, "Smith 21.4"
Мне нужно отделить 21.4 и записать его отдельно. 
В нэте я нашел кое-что про Matcher, но не понял как его использовать.
Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: Язык может укажете? Что за дебильная метка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Метод Split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29). Например:

```
String buf = new String("Smith 21.4");
        String[] tmp = buf.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) **
            System.out.println(tmp[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Спасибо! 
А как использовать массив вместо обычной строки в данном случае? Я могу прислать код, что я попытался сделать (там ошибка), но я не знаю, как прикрепить код.
И не могли бы вы подсказать,как можно сделать, чтоб был не вывод строки, а записывание во второй массив? Можно ли как-то прикрепить return?

Comment: давай код. Для массива, соответственно, в цикле нужно будет разбивать

Comment: public void separate(String[] str, int nlast){
  for (int i = 0; i <= nlast-1; i++) {
        String[] tmp = str[i].split(" ");
  }
        for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(tmp[i]);
        }
   }
(он весь слипся, я не знаю, как нормально его забросить)

Comment: `public static void separate(String[] str, int nlast){ 
  for (int i = 0; i <= nlast-1; i++) { 
   String[] tmp = str[i].split(" "); 
   for (int j = 0; j < tmp.length; j++) { 
    System.out.println(tmp[j]); 
   }
  }  
 }`

Comment: Область видимости у цикла, только внутри цикла. У второй цикл не знает о существовании массива tmp, поэтому нужно запускать цикл внутри цикла

Comment: Спасибо, это стало понятно.
А вот еще: я до этого изучал только алгоритмы и делал таким путем:
`Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   int n = in.nextInt();
   String[] s = new String[n];
   double[] res = new double[n];
   for (int i = 0; i <= n-1; i++) {
    s[i] = in.nextLine();   
   }
   for (int i = 0; i <= n-1; i++) {
  //тут будет перезапись во второй массив  
   }
//а тут я еще не дописал
`
Но ведь вернее будет сделать класс и отталкиваться от него? Не могли бы вы подсказать, как именно вытащить из класса значения переменных в массивы? Или продолжать делать как в примере выше?

Comment: В целом задача вот в чем:
С клавиатуры считывается натуральное число N - количество участников забега.
Далее следуют N строк с информацией о результатах забега в формате: <фамилия> <время>
Программа выводит на экран трех победителей в формате: <место> <фамилия> <время>

Comment: Короче я бы сделал два массива и с помощью сканера заполнил бы их `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
   s[i] = in.nextLine();
   String[] tmp = s[i].split(" "); 
   s[i] = tmp[0];
   res[i] = Double.valueOf(tmp[1]);
  }` 
Затем отсортировал массив с числами http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8#Java_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.80 как-нибудь так. И сохранил бы еще в одном массиве номера ячеек с самыми большими значениями. и вывел бы ячейки под данными номерами